# Why Can't launch React App after closing it?

Tags: reactjs

Complete newbie with React, and it seems so much more convoluted than anything i've experienced. the coding is easier than JavaScript. running the applications on the other hand... a complete nightmare...

Just followed a tutorial on youtube and actually managed to finish it without bugging out mid way. But 3 hours later, when I wanted to check out the project again. (just want to run the app in my browser and have a look) I go to vs code and open terminal and type in npm start (newb so idk anything, is this even what i should do? ) and it gives me this

"next start

ready - started server on 0.0.0.0:3000, url: http://localhost:3000
info  - Using webpack 5. Reason: no next.config.js https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/webpack5
Error: Could not find a production build in the 'C:\Users\Eric\Downloads\New folder\portfolio_website-STARTER.next' directory. Try building your app with 'next build' before starting the production server. https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/production-start-no-build-id
at Server.readBuildId (C:\Users\Eric\Downloads\New folder\portfolio_website-STARTER\node_modules\next\dist\next-server\server\next-server.js:151:355)
at new Server (C:\Users\Eric\Downloads\New folder\portfolio_website-STARTER\node_modules\next\dist\next-server\server\next-server.js:3:120)
at NextServer.createServer (C:\Users\Eric\Downloads\New folder\portfolio_website-STARTER\node_modules\next\dist\server\next.js:1:2935)
at async C:\Users\Eric\Downloads\New folder\portfolio_website-STARTER\node_modules\next\dist\server\next.js:1:3360
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! portfolio_nextjs@0.1.0 start: `next start`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the portfolio_nextjs@0.1.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Eric\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2022-03-28T02_41_25_297Z-debug.log"

I can't even begin to decipher with all that was. this is why i'm having so much trouble with React, it's always a complete wall of text... can someone please explain what's going on?

Comment: sorry i don't quite follow what do you mean by "i need to build my project"? I finished building the page. closed it, went for dinner, came back and try to start the app again. and it gives me error messages.

Comment: Try to keep the post centered on the question and not around your personal thoughts on the framework.